# XNA game studio simplest sprite animation

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

Ok so i want to animate my "Hero" = Rectangle sprite i want to make very simple animation i have 2 images first(Hero sprite facing right) second image(Hero sprite facing left) the images size is equal everything its ok.All i want is whenever i move right or left my  Hero Sprite image changes to Image facing right of Image facing left and i have no clue how to do that.
If someone can post an simple algorith to do that i will be very thankful thank you.

Basicly i move right/left with Left/Right Arrows so when i press Right Arrow i want my Hero Image to be replaced with choosed from me image and same if i press Left Arrow

If you require more information to help me ask me.

Answer (score 1):

Make a sprite class, implementing animation in it (preferebly using sprite sheets), and when the left arrow is pressed: `PlayerSprite = PlayerSpriteLeft` and when the right arrow is pressed, do it the other way.

Object oriented programming comes in really handy at this point, so make use of it!

Make a `Sprite` class exposing the methods `Draw(SpriteBatch sBatch)`, `Update(float time)` and the properties `Interval` and `NumberOfFrames` or something like that.

Be creative!

Answer (score 0):

The platformer example on the [Microsoft website](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/platformer) is a good place to start.  It has a Sprite animation class that you'll be able to learn from.